# Listview android

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

Como posso separar os campos retornados de um *SQLite database* em um *listview*?
Estou utilizando:

```
SimpleCursorAdapter adaptador = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.row_item, registros, from, to, 0);
```

Eele retorna os campos corretamente, mas aparecem assim no listview:

> Campo1Campo2Campo3

Eu queria que aparecesse assim:

> Campo1     Campo2     Campo3

Arquivo "row_item":

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#ECEFF1"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:padding="3dp">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/col1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:text="Large Text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:layout_span="1" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/col2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:text="Large Text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:layout_span="1" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/col3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:text="Large Text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:layout_span="1" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/col4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:visibility="invisible"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:text="Large Text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:layout_span="1" />
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

Comment: Cadê a parte do código onde é atribuído os valores para `registros`?

Comment: Seria possível postar uma imagem de como ele está se adaptando no Listview ?